# .htaccess Allow specific file to access

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all pages on index.html page.

For that I use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.siteurl.com [R=permanent,L]
```

But I want some other files to access like, robots.txt and a .json file

How to manage both permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude those files using a negitive RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !json$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.siteurl.com [R=permanent,L]
```

Clear your browsers cache before testing this.

Comment: due to this code web page has been trapped in a redirect loop

Comment: @Sach I think it was due to the index.html file, it was getting redirected to itself. I have excluded it in the code.

Comment: Still same problem.

Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.html


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots\.txt$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !json$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.webdevelopmentzones.com [R=permanent,L]